# Why am I getting this error when I run loaddata?

Tags: python, django, database, heroku, django-models

I am trying to run `heroku python manage.py loaddata db.json` but I keep getting this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 2446: invalid start byte`.

What I did:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`  locally
2. git pushed to repo to update changes
3. `heroku python manage.py migrate`
4. `heroku python manage.py loaddata db.json`

I keep getting this problem where I make changes to the database locally, the changes will not be reflected when I deploy on heroku.

1. I added new rows locally, these rows do not get added to postgres when I deploy on heroku.
2. No table or data on postgres when I deploy on heroku.

I deployed the app through connecting to github.

Comment: How did you create `db.json`?

Comment: I ran ```python manage.py dumpdata db.json``` in the terminal.

Comment: check your db.json has valid json using some online json parser,  try http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: You should check what encoding have char with code `0x97` - and this could explain all. I tested it with different encoding and for `UTF-8` and `Latin1` I get errro but `cp1250` gives me char `—` . Chec code: `print( b'\x97'.decode('cp1250') )`. It may mean you use Windows and it may save it with encoding `cp1250'`